# Why jqgrid can't get json data from joomla?

Tags: ajax, json, joomla, jqgrid

I write codes for using jqgrid(version 4.4.4) in joomla(version 2.5.9).this is my codes  I found the jqgrid cann't display data from joomla json_encode.but no in joomla is OK.
if jqgrid url:testjson.php is ok.

```
<?php
  header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
  header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
  header("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8");
 header('Content-Disposition,attachment;filename=”json.json”');
  $response=new stdClass();
  $response->page = 1; 
  $response->total = 1; 
  $response->records = 1; 
  $response->rows[0]['id']='1';
   $response->rows[0]['cell']=array("1","vlan");
  echo json_encode($response);
?
```

I get json:{"page":1,"total":1,"records":1,"rows":[{"id":"1","cell":["1","vlan"]}]},and jqgrid work fine.

When jqgrid url:index.php?option=com_sysconfig&view=vlan&task=ajaxvlane.getvlanlist&format=raw

In sub-controller,in function getvlanlist,this codes is blow:

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8");
header('Content-Disposition,attachment;filename=”json.json”');
$response=new stdClass();
$response->page = 1; 
$response->total = 1; 
$response->records = 1; 
$response->rows[0]['id']='1';
$response->rows[0]['cell']=array("1","vlan");
echo json_encode($response);
JFactory::getApplication()->close();
?>
```

Through firebug i can see the json:{"page":1,"total":1,"records":1,"rows":[{"id":"1","cell":["1","vlan"]}]} same as testjson.php result.

but jqgrid can't show any data.

What error causes a problem？thank you.

BTW,if I use joomla creating xml data ,jqgrid work fine.

Comment: I get the answer:because the code editor is UTF8 BOM charaset.If use no BOM uft-8,then it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I get the answer:because the code editor is UTF8 BOM charaset.If use no BOM uft-8,then it work fine.